# How to run a HTTP request again, in between of other multiple requests

Tags: jmeter

I am using the concept of the simple controller.
1. I have created an SC "X" in which, using multiple HTTP requests.
2. Created another SC "Y" in which, using multiple HTTP requests.

After running these two SC, I want to run SC "X" requests again, before another SC "Z".But don't want to create another SC to perform the task of SC "X".

Please Suggest in this.

Answer (score 2):

Add a [Module Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) where do you want to execute your `SC "X"` and configure it to run `SC "X"` like:

[image: JMeter Module Controller]

Once you run your test the Module Controller will execute `SC "X"` (including all children)

[image: JMeter Module Controller]

More information: [Easily Write a GOTO Statement in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/easily-write-a-goto-statement-in-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri I was using the Module Controller but did not think, to do the same with this.